# How to rotate a square shaped element over its diagonal axis with CSS?

Tags: css

Given a square, how can I rotate it such as the element flips with its diagonal being the origin of rotation? I managed to flip it using:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(-90deg);
```

you can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ewGWj/1/)

but this does not rotate on the diagonal axis. How can I achieve that? Basically what I am trying to achieve is that when the element rotates, its top right corner, and bottom left corner don't go out of place.. Thanks and sorry for my bad English/explanation :S!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like I'm a bit late to the party, but

```
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(-2,1, 0,-180deg);
```

may give you the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YadZe/3/), a combination of [matrix-transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#matrix) and [scaling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#scale) works. [with a background-image](http://jsfiddle.net/YadZe/4/) the effect gets more obvious.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that my element is wrapped in a div with "perspective".I don't think that we need to change the scale value considering this..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just need to add this:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: left bottom
```

If that isn't it exactly look here for information on how to change the origin of the rotation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: thanks, but that just makes the bottom left corner stay on the same place (like i wanted). The top right one still moves..

Comment: I think you just need to rotate x y and z very carefully in the correct ratios to prevent the top right corner from moving. But I don't know the right formula to make that happen.

Comment: I managed to rotate it almost (the "fixed" corners are the other two..) like I wanted it: http://jsfiddle.net/ewGWj/2/